# How to store the connection variable after the connection

Tags: database, node.js

Like most node applications, mine has a database connection. This means that nearly all routes need the `db` variable to be functional. At the moment, in my app.js, I have:

```
var globals = require('globals');

/* ... */

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost/database", function( err, db ) {
  if( err ){
    console.log("Error establishing mongo connection: ", err );
    process.exit( 1 );
  }
  console.log( "DB Connected, ready to go!" );
  globals.db = db;
});

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
/* ... etc, the standard express stuff */
```

And `globals.js` is:

```
module.exports = {
  db: null
}
```

So, any module requiring `global.js` will have access to the `db` variable, which will be valid *once the connection is established*.

Is this a good way to go about it?
I wonder if, instead, I should:

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost/database", function( err, db ) {
  if( err ){
    console.log("Error establishing mongo connection: ", err );
    process.exit( 1 );
  }
  console.log( "DB Connected, ready to go!" );
  globals.db = db;

  // view engine setup
  app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  /* ... etc, the standard express stuff */

});
```

Where the routes are only defined once the database connection has happened.

However, even then the default Express 4 program `www` will do:

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
```

But it will effectively do that *before* app is actually completely "done" (since routes are only added once the database connection is established).

So... am I missing something? Where should I actually store `db`, and should I *actually* wait for it to be ready before adding routes?

Answer (score -1):

One possibility is to treat the DB connection-handle as a "singleton."  In other words, use a *function* (maybe, a function of the prototype, hence a "class function") to obtain it.  This function stashes a copy of the handle in a private, static variable.  If that variable is `null`, then the function obtains the db-handle and stashes it.  Thus, the *first* request to get a database-handle will allocate it, and every *subsequent* request will return the same handle.

If you have timing-issues such that "certain things can't be done until a database handle is established, *and* a database handle can't be established yet," your design obviously gets a whole lot more tricky.  ("Messy lists-of-closures foo" ...)  But maybe that's not really an issue here.

Comment: Note that in this case `globals.js` is indeed a sort of singleton object with a db attribute, which becomes "correct" once the connection is established. So, that's kind of already the case...

Comment: Not necessarily, Merc.  (Yes, I know what you're saying but I want to clarify here ...)  My suggestion, to use a *function* instead of an *attribute,* is specifically so that the handle will be initialized "on demand," and the caller will always wind up with a valid handle.  Now, such a function might well stash that handle (once it has obtained it ...) in `globals.js`.  But "everyone is on-their-honor to pretend that the stash really doesn't exist.  If you want a DB-handle, the one-and-only correct way to get one is to:  call that function."

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. You are saying to use an asynchronous function that requires a callback parameter, get that function to cache the result, and use that function to obtain the DB variable every time I want to, from wherever I want it. Right?

Comment: Nope... much simpler than that.  "No callback, not asynchronous."  *(As I envision it ...)* When you call this function, it will return a database-handle to you immediately.  It will do so by checking its "secret stash."  If the "secret stash" has a handle, that's the handle that you get.  Otherwise, the function will coin a new handle, store it in the "secret stash," and return it to you.  The first caller will cause a new handle to be created, on-demand. All subsequent callers will get the same handle.

Comment: NOTE:  It wasn't entirely clear to me, from your original description, whether you, in fact, *do* need some kind of callback.  *e.g.,* if someone might have need to request that a certain unit of work be done "as soon as a database-handle *can* be obtained."  If that added-complexity *is* part of your picture, then yes, a callback would be needed.  The function would have to store the callbacks in a list, and then, whenever a database handle *can* be obtained, call all the callbacks.  (Otherwise, it would just call the callback immediately.)   So it goes.

Comment: "Otherwise, the function will coin a new handle, store it in the "secret stash," and return it to you." You can't "return it", because the db is obtained with an async call. So, "returning it" here means "call a callback" -- you cannot "return it" in the classical sense.

Comment: Okay, I didn't see that the db-handle had to be obtained *asynchronously* in your situation.

Comment: My example code does say `MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost/database", function( err, db ) {`. Plus, having a handle means establishing a connection, which is by definition an asynchronous operation...